# Date operations in Java already passed or near in the future

Tags: java, calendar

In Java (I'm a junior) - how do you perform various date operations?

Assess "storedDate is one week away from today" and "storedDate has passed"

I am not sure if its the best approach or how to do the condition check

```
java.sql.Date  dueDate = (Date) loggedUser.get("dueDate");
```

I've seen various calculations like this - but not sure an if condition could be met like this?

```
Calendar c= Calendar.getInstance();
//c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,Calendar.SUNDAY);
c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,0);
c.set(Calendar.MINUTE,0);
c.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);
DateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("EEE yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
System.out.println(df.format(c.getTime()));// This past Sunday [ May include today ]
c.add(Calendar.DATE,7);
System.out.println(df.format(c.getTime()));// Next Sunday
```

Comment: You should check Joda Time, or native new Java time APi if you're using java 8 if you're doing this for java side. If you're trying to make a SQL Query, it's not appropriate... You should provide more details.

Comment: I recomment moving on to java.time, the new time/date API with java 8. It is more sophisticated and simpler

Comment: @HoussemBdr - when you say Java 8 - you mean to upgrade my Tomcat from 7 to 8? -- What is Joda Time - a new depencie? -@Mateo Barahona

Comment: @Rob : http://www.joda.org/joda-time/
You should explain what you're trying to achieve, i'm not sure you're going the right way

Comment: @Rob No, it means to use the Java 8 classes for handling dates. Joda time is an alternative API for dates in Java.

Comment: Rob, this is not the first time I had to remove [java-ee] tag from your question. Please take that as a hint to pay extra attention to your tagging. General rule is, if your problem is demonstrable using a plain vanilla Java application class with `main()` method, then it's very definitely not [java-ee] related.

Comment: Well I didn't know that @BalusC - I tried to tag it J2EE - if I wasn't doing UX, Design, Frontend and Backend development I would have made more of an effort to notice your edit hints.

Comment: J2EE has been renamed to Java EE since 2006. More than a decade ago.

Comment: Sure ok I'll take note

Comment: FYI, both the `Calendar` class and the Joda-Time project are now outmoded by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Learn to read API pages.
Here is the [Calendar API Page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), read it.

For your class project, you don't care about timezone (since you didn't mention it in your post).

Get a date parameter:  `public void methodName(Date dateParameter)`

Create a `Calendar` containing now: Calendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

Set a calendar to a date value: `myCalendar.setTime(dateParameter)`

"Calculate" one week from today: `myCalendar.roll(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 7)`

The Calendar object stores Millisecond, Second, Minute, and Hour.
Clear these using the `set` method.

Compare Calendar objects using the `after` method.

Comment: "Compare Calendar objects using the after method." - please elaborate --- like a .equals?

Comment: Read the Calendar api page.

Comment: The troublesome `Calendar` class has been outmoded for years, supplanted by the *java.time* classes built into Java 8 and later. For Java 6 & 7, see the *ThreeTen-Backport* project.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) )
.with( 
    TemporalAdjusters.previousOrSame​( DayOfWeek.SUNDAY ) 
)
```

## java.time

The modern approach uses java.time classes.

Get current moment in UTC.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;
```

If you care about day-of-week, you care about date. Determining a date requires a time zone. For any given moment the date varies around the globe by zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;  // Same point on the timeline, different wall-clock time.
```

To focus on date-only without time-of-day, extract a `LocalDate`.

```
LocalDate ld = zdt.toLocalDate() ;
```

To adjust into other moments, use a [`TemporalAdjuster`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjuster.html). Find implementations in [`TemporalAdjusters`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html).

```
LocalDate previousOrSameSunday = ld.with( 
    TemporalAdjusters.previousOrSame​( DayOfWeek.SUNDAY ) 
) ;
```

…and…

```
LocalDate nextOrSameSunday = ld.with( 
    TemporalAdjusters.nextOrSame​( DayOfWeek.SUNDAY ) 
) ;
```

To compare, look for `isBefore`, `isAfter`, `isEqual`, and `equals` methods on the various java.time classes.

```
thisLocalDate.isBefore( thatLocalDate)
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).